# How to check if email domain is a gmail in php and then strip out "@gmail.*"?

Tags: php, string

This is a two-part question. Help on either (or both) is appreciated!

1) What is the best php method for checking if an email string is a Gmail address

2) How to strip out everything but the username?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you need something more than basic string manipulation?

Comment: No. I'm just trying to identify a Google username from an email address for Embedly integration.   :)

Comment: In that case this question is just about basic string manipulation in general. There's nothing special about gmail being involved here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
list($user, $domain) = explode('@', $email);

if ($domain == 'gmail.com') {
    // use gmail
}

echo $user;
// if $email is toto@gmail.com then $user is toto
```

Comment: Thanks to a certain a..hole you also need to check if the domain is `googlemail.com` (german users cannot create `@gmail.com` addresses without using a foreign proxy). You might also `strtolower()` the domain name as domains are case insensitive but some people like to write in caps.

Comment: UK users too up until recently.

Comment: fredley / Theif, I am sure he can figure out how to modify it if needed. An example is good enough, imo. Especially with lack of trial code.

Answer (score 2):

Dunno about best method, but here is one method for checking a gmail address using [`stristr`](http://php.net/stristr).

```
if (stristr($email, '@gmail.com') !== false) {
    echo 'Gmail Address!';
}
```

As for pulling out the username there are a ton of functions as well, one could be [`explode`](http://www.php.net/explode):

```
$username = array_shift(explode('@', $email));
```

There are many ways to do it, the best depends on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

For Multiple Emails

```
$expressions = 
"/(gmail|googlmail|yahoo|hotmail|aol|msn|live|rediff|outlook|facebook)/";
if (preg_match($expressions, $input_email)) {
    throw error   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match("/gmail.com/",$email_address)) {
  $email_address = str_replace("@gmail.com","",$email_address);
}
```